# Issue with label height in iOS

Tags: ios, storyboard, uilabel

I my project we are using a custom font in labels with line spacing(So using attributed text). All the labels are inside a scrollview with, and are constrained so that the height of scroll view is calculated Automatically. This all works fine when I run the Xcode and view the app when its Xcode is running. But when I Stop the Xcode and launch the app directly from the simulator the labels have the last line invisible. To fix this temporarily I have constrained the label height, so that all the lines are visible.
But why is it occurring, how do I resolve it?

Comment: Please review [ask]. We need a lot more information about how you are constraining your labels, as well as how (and when) you are setting properties.

Comment: The label is constrained to top leading and trailing safe area edges. And the label below it top is constrained to the first label bottom edge, then leading and trailing safe area edges.

Comment: If your constraints are set correctly, it shouldn't be an issue. Try putting together a [mre] -- very tough to answer a question without being able to see what's happening.